# Multiline labels in flex 4.5 mobile apps?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

im completely lost on how to do a simple multiline label. The docs say that labels are best used as single lined elements, but that alludes to it being able to do multiline if necessary. Anyone have any clarification on the subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<s:Label>
    first line
    second line
</s:Label>
```

or this way:

```
<s:Label text="first line{'\n'}second line"/>
```

Comment: Alright, say its dynamic text and i cant insert new lines. Like a way to line break depending on the width of the display.

Comment: If you need the text to wrap, instead of specifying breaks explicitly,  specify a width for your label, for example:
<s:Label width="75" text="some long piece of text that should wrap eventually..."/>

Comment: @sixfeesix According to docs, the lineBreak style is not supported on Mobile.  I'm not sure if what you suggest will work.  (Doc Link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html#styleSummary )

Comment: Yeah sixfeetsix's suggestion worked. I had width 100% on a vgroup with a label in it expecting it would inherit, but it didnt. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a label, can you use a [StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html)?  If so, just set the [wordWrap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#wordWrap) property to true.